# How to get behavior of Group.Captures (from RegEx in C#) in Java?

Tags: c#, java, regex

What I am looking for is to mimic behavior of C# regular expression (that I really like) in Java's regular expression API in a most easy-to-use way.

Basically, C# allows you to catch closures of "nested" groups in regular expression by allowing you to access `Captures` attribute of a `Group` object instances inside `Match`es. Description of the feature is here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx).

For example, look at the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(abc((([\\d]+)\\s?)+)def\\s?)+?");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("abc123def abc567 341 123 789def");

    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
    }
}
```

Output in Java is:

```
123
789
```

So, as you can see Java can not see other captures except (last) 789. In C# you would be able to see 567, 341, 123 and 789 inside `Captures` attribute.

Unfortunately I see that in Java I have access only to one capture of the nested group `([\\d]+)`, I can't see to find a way to catch the other captures of the nested group. The question is basically "*am I missing something here?*".

I **know** that I can just use another regex matcher on the match string of a larger group. I wish though to have it all in a single big RegEx which is filled with comments and easy to test in a (pretty cool) tool "Regulator v2". I also know that the upper example can be done without the nested group, but this is just a rough example based on a real-life log parser RegEx with >20 groups, just to explain what is the problem.

EDIT: I introduced entire Java example to avoid misinterpretation of the problem.

Comment: This is how usual regex flavors work, only one value per capturing group is saved, .NET is an exception. `\d+` would work just fine for your example. Feel free to provide a more complete case/example so we could help you with that.

Comment: I tried to be as exact as possible in the above example, the real-life example would render this question unreadable because of the regex complexity. I do, on the other hand, acknowledge what you say and will try to forget about the .Net way and refactor regex to a more suitable and more straightforward approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to achieve this in java.
Java `Matcher` class will return last match of subgroup within each match.
That is:

For regex: `(\w(\d))+` on string `a1b2c3`

the returned groups will be ["a1b2c3", "c3", "3"].

If the regex is changed to `(\w(\d))` then it will return matches:

`["a1", "a1", "1"]`, `["b2", "b2", "2"]`, `["c3", "c3", "3"]`

Comment: Your avatar is missing a trollface. (-;

Comment: Thanks, I think also at this time that it simply is just not possible to do it in Java without additional regex in matching groups of first level regex

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `Matcher` object, you can loop through all matches and get the groups for each match.

Basically you do this:

```
while( matcher.find() ) {
  matcher.group(3); //group 0 is the entire match, group 1 and 2 are the outer groups
}
```

Note, however, that your regex needs some adjustments, since it would match `abc567 341 123def` for example. AFAIK you can't get the groups 567 341 and 123 from one match, if that's what you want.

What you could do is use this expression to get the number groups between `abc` and `def`, and in a second step split those groups: `(?<=abc)((?:\d+\s?)+)(?=def)`

This expression would return `123` and `567 341 123` and splitting those at whitespace would result in an string array with each individual number, i.e. `"123".split("\\s+")`->`{"123"}` and  `"567 341 123".split("\\s+")`-> `{"567", "341", "123"}`

Comment: Agreed that is one way to go. I would like to avoid that approach  though if I can, since in C# I don't have to go down that longer way.